# preventing selection on MKPointAnnotation

Tags: objective-c, ios, mkmapview

Is there a way to prevent an annotation in a MKMapView instance from being enabled. In other words, when the user taps the red pin on the map, is there a way to prevent it from highlighting the pin. Right now the pin turns dark when touched...

**Edit:** I'm using the following code to return the MKPinAnnotationView

```
// To future MKMapView users - Don't forget to set _mapView's delegate
_mapView.delegate = self;

_annotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];

_annotation.coordinate = myLocation;

[_mapView addAnnotation:_annotation];


-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation{

MKPinAnnotationView *pin = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:_annotation reuseIdentifier:@"id"];
pin.enabled = NO;

return pin;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set `enabled` to `NO` on your `MKPinAnnotationView`, which you return from your `-mapView:viewForAnnotation:` delegate method (if you haven't implemented it, do it).

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation 
{
    static NSString *annotationIdentifier = @"Annotation";
    MKPinAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:annotationIdentifier];

    if (!annotationView) {
        annotationView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:annotationIdentifier];
    }
    else {
        annotationView.annotation = annotation;
    }

    annotationView.enabled = NO;

    return annotationView;
}
```

Comment: ok so I implemented the delegate method but its still allowing me to select the pin...I also added my code in viewDidLoad where I initialize the pin in the first place.

Comment: @Derek Have you set the map view's delegate?

Comment: Thanks so much. I hadn't set the delegate. I have edited my question with the proper source code. Thanks again you've been really helpful.